# Filter for certain words and color code them

Tags: google-sheets

I have a FILTER sheet with a list of all the fruits I want to color code. In my Basket sheet there is a column Fruit. Whenever the Item in the Basket appears in the FILTER list, I want to change the color to yellow. Is that possible?

[Example sheet >](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HvjHZOwAuRkSs9tE1p4_ZmsUDr8t6DFGedwwS1eKvNc/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [condional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) rule with

`Custom formula is`

`=countif(indirect("FILTER!A$1:A$10"), A1)>0`

You need to use `indirect()` to be able to refer to a different within a conditional formatting statement.

Comment: Indirect was the missing piece. Thank you! It works.

Comment: Hi ziganotschka, I struggle with one more thing. Currently if I change "Banana" to "Banana something" the conditional formatting doesn't change the color anymore. I tried `=RegExMatch(A2,INDIRECT("FILTER!A1:A"))` but that didn't solve it.

Comment: Would  "Banana something"  be the content of `Basket` or `FILTER`?

Comment: It would be in the Basket.

Comment: This might be a bit tricky, if you have a fixed delimiter (e.g. an empty space) between `Banana` and `something`, you can use the formula `=countif(indirect("FILTER!A$1:A$10"), index(split(A1," ", false),,1))>0`

Comment: Space is perfect as delimiter. It works. `INDEX(SPLIT(A2," ", false),,1`. Could you explain me what happens in that part here?

Comment: You split the text in two parts - left and right from the delimiter and with `INDEX(text,row,column)` you specify that you are interested only in the first part of the text that has been split into two columns (since there is only one row, you can skip the `1` for row in `INDEX(SPLIT(A2," ", false),1,1`)

Comment: I just saw that at one case there is unfortunately no space at delimiter but //. So it seems like the split function doesn't solve my problem completely. Maybe if I drop the idea of using INDIRECT, but rather mark the entries directly which are in my filter list, could that solve it?